# Copy rows from one database to another

Tags: mysql

I have two databases with the same schema (dev/prod) hosted on different machines (and different hosts).

Is there any mechanism or tool whereby I can do a select against specific rows in one db and insert them into the other?

Comment: SQL will; that might be really difficult/impossible in MySQL though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQL's [`FEDERATED`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/federated-storage-engine.html) storage engine:

> The `FEDERATED` storage engine lets you access data from a remote MySQL database without using replication or cluster technology. Querying a local `FEDERATED` table automatically pulls the data from the remote (federated) tables. No data is stored on the local tables.

So, to create a connection:

```
CREATE TABLE federated_table (
    id     INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    other  INT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY  (id),
    INDEX name (name),
    INDEX other_key (other)
)
ENGINE=FEDERATED
DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
CONNECTION='mysql://fed_user@remote_host:9306/federated/test_table';
```

Having defined such a table, you could then perform [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html) as you see fit:

```
INSERT INTO federated_table SELECT * FROM local_table WHERE ...
```

Or

```
INSERT INTO local_table SELECT * FROM federated_table WHERE ...
```

If you are federating multiple tables from the same server, you may wish to use [`CREATE SERVER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/federated-create-server.html) instead.

Comment: @GeniaS.: Of course, a more mundane approach would be to [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select-into.html), copy the file to the target machine and then [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html).  At the other end of the spectrum are advanced database control systems, like [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) and [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org/)—although they're more for managing schema changes than copying across records;  still probably worth mentioning them here just in case it's useful for you or future readers.